# How to make a unique id for <input> and <label> tags in gotemplate in {{ define "..." }}?

Tags: go, go-templates, go-html-template

With `{{ define "something" }}` we can reuse some html code:

```
{{ template "something" . }}
{{ template "something" . }}
{{ template "something" . }}
```

And this is great but sometimes (honestly pretty often) we need use id's. The most common case is when you write a form with inputs and labels with 'for' attribute. And for some a11y things too.

But if I write something like:

```
{{ define "something" }}
<label for="best-input">Best label</label>
<p>...</p>
<input  id="best-input">
{{ .some.data.I.need.from.dot.var }}
{{ end }}

{{ template "something" . }}
{{ template "something" . }}
{{ template "something" . }}
```

Of course, I'll get 3 inputs with the same id. So, my labels will be working wrong, and there will be warnings in the console.

Also, I even can't write `{{ template "t" "id1" }} {{template "t" "id2" }}` because I need '.' variable too.

So, how can I fix that? Is there any easy way?

Comment: Make the IDs unique using the data passed to the child template?

Comment: @Adrian yeah, but I need '.' variable inside

Comment: Right. So use some data in the `.` variable to differentiate the IDs. It's impossible to give any more specific advice because you haven't given any of the Go code involved to define whatever type `.` is or to execute the template.

Comment: @Adrian Does it matter? There's a minimal sample: https://play.golang.org/p/qEHQgPxr0HD . What can I do to get output as here https://play.golang.org/p/Etec4HFt8gl ?

Comment: You can't with that example, which is why the code matters.

Comment: @Adrian are there some ways to do that (with some changes in 'go' or 'template' parts)?
I mean... I'm so confused.. How can I use any `{{ define "" }}` with any id attributes inside then?

Comment: See my earlier comment - you would need to use something from the data the fragment receives to differentiate the IDs.

Comment: You should do something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/ctVnmGd9I3Z. Alternatively you could write a function that extracts the id from the title and register it for the template, although, in my opinion, that's the lesser approach of the two.

Comment: @Adrian
@mkopriva yeah that's obvious. But I can't use it so. All my "templates" use the same data (from go). For example I what place 2 payment forms on the page. Of course I don't want to repeat html. So, I just want to make {{ define }} template.  There's `.cards` with cards data  and some id's in the forms (user can select a card or enter card's info)

Comment: @DmitryGashko your last comment is confusing and it is unclear why you "can't use" the proposed solutions. What is wrong with using a `range` in the template and a proper Go struct with multiple fields for the different values you want to render?

Comment: @Adrian I find the solution. Honestly there's even no problem. All I need is... https://play.golang.org/p/LxmS6lagOJ9

Comment: @mkopriva see above

Comment: @DmitryGashko be very, very careful with how you use that in your actual code. Works in your example, but can catch fire in a web server handling concurrent requests.

Comment: @DmitryGashko as Adrian commented, your solution is not concurrency safe, so don't do it. Here's an approach that utilizes the index from the template `range` action: https://play.golang.org/p/Pn98VMR4Ux1

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks, you're rigth! I did't think about this. But range - I can't use it in my case because I don't need to paste one form twice sequentially (for example, one at the beginning of the page, second at the end).

Comment: @DmitryGashko range is not really important, what's important is how you pass the title and the id together to the defined template. https://play.golang.org/p/f5sXhWrS0u0

Comment: @mkopriva thanks, that's I tried to do (and hadn't got it when you said in the biggining).  What do you think about solution with function that just generate unique id (and is concurrency safe)?

Comment: @DmitryGashko if it's concurrency safe and it works for you then I don't see a problem.

Answer (score 0):

So.. all I need is...

```
{{ define "something" }}

{{ $id := uniqueId }}

<label for="{{ $id }}">Best label</label>
<p>...</p>
<input  id="{{ $id }}">
{{ .some.data.I.need.from.dot.var }}
{{ end }}

{{ template "something" . }}
{{ template "something" . }}
{{ template "something" . }}
```

Where `uniqueId` - is just a function defined in template.FuncMap